# How to get string value from raw HTML in Java?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

Actually, I'm downloading HTML code with iON library and in this HTML page there is just a string like `|5.00|` or it can be `|10.00|`. So how can I get the value that is in middle of `|`?

The problem is that I don't have the exact string `|10.00|` but all the HTML code so I have to use something like `if(htmlstring.contains("|")`.

But then, I can't get how to get the value from that `|`.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the downloaded code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()`

```
    String htmlstring = "abcd|10.0|1234";
    int firstIndex = htmlstring.indexOf('|');
    int lastIndex = htmlstring.indexOf('|',firstIndex+1);

    String value = htmlstring.substring(firstIndex+1, lastIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
String val = "|10.00|";
String output[] = val.split("\\|",val.length());
val = output[1].substring(0,val.length()-2);
```